# how to install two ubuntus?

Tags: dual-boot, edubuntu

I have edubuntu and I have installed ubuntu64. but only edubuntu is booting. how to make grub understand that there are 2 ubuntus.

Comment: Please add some more information on your disk configuration. `sudo fdisk -l` and specify what is installed on which partition/disk.

Answer (score 2):

run as`sudo  update-grub2` in your terminal to update the configuration.